# Restore .bak on Azure SQL database through SSMS: Failed to connect to Server ***. Login Failed for user ***

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am trying to restored a .bak file on an Azure SQL server through SSMS.

The reason why I am doing this is that my company unfortunately blocked any action on the Azure portal itself and therefore I have to find another way around.

I am able to connect successfully to the DB on Azure with my admin account through SSMS.

I first successfully restored the .bak on my local database. And then I am trying:

[image]

Again, I am able to connect through the same SSMS to the SQL db.
Moreover, when starting this procedure I get asked to connect first to the DB, which works successfully! What I mean is:

[image]

It doesn't give me any error, which is weird because if I try to connect with a wrong password it tells me right away that is wrong. So it kind of accepts it. It's only after when I really start the deployment that it gives me the problem:

[image]

Comment: Deploy isn't for restoring databases; Restore is for restoring databases. If you can't upload a `bak` file to a file storage area the instance has access to, have you considered using a DACPAC/BACPAC?

Comment: @Larnu thanks for your answer first of all! Deploying or Restoring doesn't matter I believe.. deploying is when you have nothing on the target side, restoring is when you have already something and want to restore data. In my case I have this .bak file that I "restored" locally and now I need to bring it somehow to the Azure Sql. Only thing in my possession is the .bak . Not a big expert in this field but even if I was able to make a dacpac from SSMS it won't contain any data right? To me the data of the .bak is what matters

Comment: @Larnu okey realized that the BACPAC contains data and can be created from SSMS. Trying to figure out in the meantime if it can be useful due to the fact the hosting agent that deploys on Azure is hosted on a VM where I don't have access.. see where I am going, problems of working in a big company. But still wondering why that Task to deploy the DB is not working as explained in my question

Comment: Hi @Tarta, is the error solved now？

Comment: @LeonYue unfortunately not yet. Trying today the "Export Data" task I got suggested by another source but I expect the same result of the publish task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution was to use the export data task:

[image]

For some reason this worked and the publish to ASQL task from SSMS didn't. I understand this is very based on the restrictions imposed by my company but at least this solution worked.

NOTE: as both Source and Destination use SQL Server Native Client .
Moreover when setting the Destination the refresh of the list of databases might not work (depending on your permissions on Server level) but if you type directly the name of the database it will work. Talking about this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for now, Azure SQL database doesn't support restore from .bak file.

You work flow should be right, restore the .bak file(database) into a local SQL Server firstly, then deploy the restored database to Azure with "Deploy database to Microsoft Azure SQL database".

Make sure you are using the server admin account of the Azure SQL database. Per my experience, the error is usually caused by the permission limits.

If all of these(SSMS) don't work, please thy other ways. Please try [Data Migration Assistant(DMA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) migrate the database. If DMA still give the same error, we can ensure that it's not caused by the tools, you need another higher Azure SQL database account permission.

HTH.